# How to search through unknown property name in database with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-json

I'm trying to search database with json contains method of laravel. Here is my JSON of one database line:

```
{
    "row": {
        "1": {
            "ID":"110555175667"
        },
        "2": {
            "ID":"11023235667"
        },
        "3": {
            "ID":"11001414141667"
        },
        "4": {
            "ID":"11023235667"
        },
        "5": {
            "ID":"1100012222225667"
        },
    }
}
```

I want to search ID, but as you see there are numbers as properties.

In example I want to find `11023235667`. I've tried it like that:

```
->whereJsonContains('json', [['row' => ['1' => ['ID' => '11023235667']]]])
```

But it didn't worked. How can I do it?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried this:

```
->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(json, "$.row.*.ID", "11023235667")')
```

I know the property of `row` must be JSON array to accomplish to match the id, but it has been set as JSON object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of [JSON_CONTAINS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) accepts a JSON document as its second argument, not a path.

You could use that path to extract the ID's into an array:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.row.*.ID') FROM ...
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["110555175667", "11023235667", "11001414141667", "11023235667", "1100012222225667"] |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using this, you can search the resulting array:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.row.*.ID'), 'one', '11023235667') IS NOT NULL;
```

You would need to do this using `whereRaw()` in Laravel, because Laravel doesn't have a builtin query builder function for this expression.

Tip: As soon as you reference a JSON column in the `WHERE` clause of an SQL query, your query becomes harder to write, and harder to optimize. This should be a red flag indicating your design is wrong. You would be better off storing data in normal rows and columns, not JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've applied your code as `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.row.*.ID') FROM mytable  WHERE JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.row.*.ID'), 'one', '11023235667') ` , but it has returned an empty result. By the way, thank you for your advices, I'm only a developer on a project, I'm going to inform project manager.

Comment: My apologies! I think I forgot the `IS NOT NULL` at the end. Try it now.